# Can't use get with body params by using axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I test it successfully by using postman. I get status code 200.

[image]

Using Axios in React Native 0.60.5

But when I test it on react native project, I get `Error: Request failed with status code 415`

I have no idea why.

Here is my axios code:

ApiServices.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.161:5000/',
  timeout: 3000,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  // handle error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response;
}, error => {
  // handle error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});


export const Get = async (api: string, params: object) => {
  console.log('api', api); // Account
  console.log('params', params); // { userAccount: "0989257556", userPwd: "12345" }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance.get(api, params).then(res => {
      resolve(res.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
  })
};
```

I use the function like this:

```
export const testApiGet = () => {

  const userAccount = '0989257556';
  const userPwd = '12345';

  Get('Account', { userAccount, userPwd }).then(res => {
    console.log('res ->', res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('err ->', err);
  });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

Comment: @robbannn Thanks for reply, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MayankPandav Thanks, I try to fix the issue without other library.

Comment: try to add "Content-Type"  header with value "application/json"

Comment: [Axios issue about GET with body](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787)

Comment: @jure Thanks, I add `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },` with axios.create  still get 415.

Comment: @flix Thanks for sharing the link, try all of others suggestion (like use body or params) still can't fix it, why it is so hard to use...

Comment: because axios using XHR core to fetching, and XHR itself would passing nothing in body while using GET,

Comment: @flix Thanks for your message, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at the same problem today for few hours. As far as I understood basicly you cant send GET request with body through axious. Just change the GET method to POST in your server. [You can check this topick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61759905/13218899) where I post more detailed answer about this.