# How to send body data and headers with axios get request?

Tags: reactjs, http, get, axios

I've tried

```
axios.get(url, {headers:{},data:{}})
```

But it doesn't work with this.

Comment: Why don't you use POST instead since you need to send a body data? This is advisable and a convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
const DELIVARAY = process.env.DELIVARAY;
const ekshop_delivary_api_key = process.env.DELIVARAY_API_KEY;
const ekshop_delivary_api_secret = process.env.DELIVARAY_API_SECRET;

 export const axios_parcel_track = (method: any, data: string, url: string) => {
  const options = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      "API-SECRET": ekshop_delivary_api_secret,
      "API-KEY": ekshop_delivary_api_key,
    },
    data: { parcel_no: data }, // parcel_no is my db field
    url: DELIVARAY + url,
  };

  return { ...options };
};
```

here method = "get" ;
data ="string" ;
url="string/string" ;

passed through with extra data. here data goes through body .as like post request.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you can't as the data-property seems to be ignored for GET. In the [official documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) we find:

```
// `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
// Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', and 'PATCH'
```

So you cannot put it in the config-object. And the signature of the axios#get-method does not provide a data parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, **but a bad practice**.

If you do a GET request, try to pass your values as Params instead of inside the body (In Postman under the "Params" tab).

**Backend** E. g.:

```js
const data = req.query.data;
```

**Frontend** E. g.:

```js
const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
};

const params = {
    data: 'Some Text'
};
            
const data = await axios.get(
    `${general.backendOrigin}/api/data`,
    { headers, params }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

`data` is the data to be sent as the request body.

Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008789

Answer (score -1):

You can send data in a get request by using the config object and the params option of the config object. This is a workaround and it works, but on the server the data sent is available as `request.query` not as `request.body`. Based on the example below you would access your params data on your server using `request.query.user_id`. It should be noted that using this method will also append the params to your request url which could have unintended consequences based on your specific situation. For example, the url for the request below would be sent as `example.com?user_id=1234`. You can read more about the axios request config [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

```
axios.get(
    'example.com/',
    {
        params: { user_id: 1234 },
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    },
  );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works but on the server the data sent is available as `request.query.user_id` not as `request.body.user_id`

Answer (score -1):

yeah, it's true it doesn't work to send body in Axios get even if it works in the postman or the backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You should use POST requests instead. It allows you to send data in the request body, which is not visible in the URL. This can be beneficial so as to not expose your information. Just like this:

```
axios.post(URL,{},{headers: {}});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: id,
                title: 'title is here',
                body: 'body is here',
                userId: 1
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json));
        console.warn(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot send a body in an axios GET request but for axios GET requests you can use the config object with params to send data. On the server the data sent is available as `request.query.your_value` not as `request.body.your_value`

Comment: mistakenly used get. thanks for correcting me

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know you can't send body data with GET request. With get you can have only Headers. Just simply change to POST and then you can do something like this :

```
const bodyParameters = {
      key: "value",
    };
    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}` }, 
    };
      axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user", bodyParameters, config)
      .then((res)=> {
       console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

or if you want to send headers with GET request

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: GET Body is allowed by the standards past 2014

Answer (score -2):

There is no field related to body in get method in axios you can transfer data by get the data in query in URL like this:

```js
axios.get(`url?data=${JSON.stringify(data)}`, {headers:{}})
```