# How to send body data with headers with axios get request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, postman

I am trying to get request from api that has a owner = value and date = value. Using Postman I can send a request with body json to get results. However when using Axios I can not get the results. How do I send body json to header and get results back. with Axios I am getting an empty response

does not work

```
var searchRecord = {
        owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73',
        date: '2021-09-02',
      };

      var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/records/owner',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: searchRecord,
      };
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/records/owner', config)
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
```

in Postman I can send the following in the body and get the results I need

```
{
  owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73',
  date: '2021-09-02',
}
```

output response will be:

```
{
        "instantMessage": "false",
        "isComplete": false,
        "_id": "612e5cede496ce8f1b6a244c",
        "date": "2021-08-31",
        "title": "Ming first",
        "description": "Test",
        "remindTime": "1630432800",
        "owner": "wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73",
    }
```

Comment: You are using a `get`, use `post` instead, and when specifying `method` you usually call `axios.request(config)` instead

Comment: I updated the code as you explain however now I get error request failed with status code 403

Comment: `{
  owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73',
  date: '2021-09-02',
}` where you put this at postman ? at RAW or using url encoded ?

Comment: I put it in the raw body section

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the same problem.
When I'm using the postman to test my backend - everything work ok.

So the purpose is to get data from endpoint (and as body I want to provide user email):

```
data = {
  "user_email": test@test.com
}

.get("api/test_endpoint/", config, data)
```

[How to send body data and headers with axios get request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551137/how-to-send-body-data-and-headers-with-axios-get-request)

Last comment in above topick "GET Body is allowed by the standards past 2014".

So finally is it possible or is it a correct practice?

Edit:

Of course I have to add:

It's possible to add needed data as part of get request url (but it's could not be login or pass!!!)
So for example logged in admin user has possibility to get data for some user via email like:

```
get('localhost/api/test_endpoint?user_email=test@test.com')
```

So why not use body as part of get request?